# Execute function queue loop with timeout (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, queue, settimeout

I'm facing a question here that I need to run, for example, 2 function per time, wait just 2 minutes and start run these two function again, just like a loop with a pause between the batches.
I've tried something here, and I know that my issue is, every time I start the `myFunction` with `start` function as callback I get a duplicated call. But right now, I really don't know what is the best approach to follow.

```
var count = 0;

function myFunction() {
  console.log('function called', count);

  start();
}

function batch () {
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    myFunction();
    console.log('batch', i);
  }
  console.log('--------------');
}

function start() {
  console.log('started')

  setTimeout(function() {
    batch();
  }, 2000);

  count++;
}

start();
```

Thank you for suggestions ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to execute two functions every two minutes.

Have you tried using `window.setInterval`?

```
const func1 = () => console.log('func1 called');
const func2 = () => console.log('func2 called');
window.setInterval(() => {
    func1();
    func2();
}, 1000);
```

Now, `func1` and `func2` will be called every second.